# Playing URL of MP3 from iPhone

Tags: iphone, mp3, stream

I am trying to find the best way to play a URL of an mp3. I've tried Audiostreamer but it doesn't fit my needs as it's geared towards infinite streams, and not finite streams.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer is your answer:

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error:

Comment: What if the URL needs to have a cookie passed to it?

Comment: Then you can use the [AVAudioPlayer initWithData] method.  Use an NSURLRequest to generate the proper request with the cookie, then save the response as an NSData object.